# Paypal Mass Payment API (Does Not Receive Response From paypal) with Asp.net using

Tags: asp.net, paypal, httpwebresponse

[image]I created MassPayment using MassPaymentAPI But I got Error In this Method

Input For Methods :::

```
url="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp"
postdata="METHOD=MassPay&EMAILSUBJECT=You+have+money!&RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress&CURRENCYCODE=USD&L_EMAIL0=bhaumik50%40gmail.com&L_Amt0=1.00&L_UNIQUEID0=&L_NOTE0=&USER=rserasiya_api1.gmail.com&PWD=OneIsTheLonliestNumber&VERSION=1&SOURCE=1" ;
timeout= "3600" ;
X509certificate = "Certifcate Description"


public static string HttpPost(string url, string postData, int timeout, X509Certificate x509)

{

    HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);

    objRequest.Timeout = timeout;

    objRequest.Method = "POST";

    objRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    if (null != x509)

    {

        objRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(x509);

    }

    using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))

    {
        myWriter.Write(postData);

    }

    using (WebResponse response = objRequest.GetResponse())

    {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))

        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

In this method i succesfully sent request using StreamWriter  object  but i not got Response from paypal site so what should i do ? pls reply ..

my error is :   The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

I put image of my method which throws error and Browser Error.

pls give me your suggestion
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Were there any solutions to this?

Comment: Rajnikant & Baris did my answer solve your issues? if so please mark it as a write answer and vote up for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is in Api url you are using

```
url="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp"
```

while you should use

```
url="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp"
```